# Putting Button in Frame issue - tKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, frame

I have recently started using tkinter for my programming project at school and I have been having some issues with how to insert/format buttons within my program.
I've been slowly trying to build up my program, starting with the main layout and THEN inserting functionality but at the moment, I'm very stuck with inserting buttons in the frames I've created and I haven't been able to make any progress because of it.

This is the code I've started with which creates my main window and the result it produces.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")  #creating main window for program
root.title("Point of Sale System")


TabFrame = Frame(root, width=250, height=100, bd=3, relief="groove") #creating box for editor & till tabs
TabFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

def editorClick (): #blank function for editor & till buttons
    return
def tillClick ():
    return

editorTab = Button(TabFrame, font=("arial", 25), text="Editor", command=editorClick) #creating buttons on screen
editorTab.grid(row=0, column=0)
tillTab = Button(TabFrame, font=("arial", 25), text="Till", command=tillClick)
tillTab.grid(row=0, column=1)



def clearClick(): #blank function for clear button
    return

ClearFrame = Frame(root, width=250, height=100, bd=3, relief="groove") #creating box for editor & till tabs
ClearFrame.grid(row=0, column=4)

clearButton = Button(ClearFrame, font=("arial", 25), text="Clear", command=clearClick)
clearButton.grid(row=0, column=4)


itemFrame = Frame(root, width=700, height=600, bd=5, relief="ridge") #creating basic boxes for item, receipt and total
itemFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=3)

receiptFrame = Frame(root, width=600, height=400, bd=5, relief="ridge")
receiptFrame.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=2)

totalFrame = Frame(root, width=600, height=200, bd=5, relief="ridge")
totalFrame.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: Main window frames]

However, once I try to add this code at the end (before root.mainloop() of course):

```
def AddButton():
global item_num #calls global variable
item_num += 1
item_text = "Item"+str(item_num) #concatonates text & variable
item1.config(text=item_text) #updates label text - doesn't add multiple 
item1.pack()

addButton = Button(itemFrame, text="Add Button", padx=25, pady=25, command=AddButton)
addButton.pack()
```

the size of the window completely changes to fit snug around the button instead of staying the same size, with the button simply being inside of it like this:
[image: Incorrect Output]

This is kind of what I want to end up with, and although how I'm going to position them in the frame are a whole other issue, I'm just trying to focus on simply button a functioning button in the frame.
[image: Desired result with buttons]

Could someone please explain what I have to do to just put the button in the frame instead of the frame changing to fit around it? I'm not sure if it has to do with how I pack it (although I have tried using .grid which results in nothing appearing)? So I'd really appreciate some help :)

(also any guidance on any ways which will help in position the buttons like that instead of simply just adding like 15 rows and columns would also be appreciated although I understand if I  need to make a separate question for this :)) )

Comment: `itemFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')` and `addButtonFrame.pack( expand=1, fill='both')`

Comment: thank you very much for this answer :) however, this still changes the size of the itemFrame as it expands vertically and the button's functionality still doesn't work
Also I'm not entirely sure if my edit hadn't gone through but instead of changing addButtonFrame, I instead did addButton.pack(expand=1, fill='both') since I realised the additional frame wasn't needed (unless it was?)

Comment: `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)`. Create and assign `item_num = 0` outside the `AddButton` also create `item1 = Label(itemFrame)
item1.pack()` outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
item_num = 0

def AddButton():
    global item_num #calls global variable
    for x in range(1):                        ###try with for loop
        item_num += 1
        item_text = "Item"+str(item_num) #concatonates text & variable
        item1 = Button(itemFrame, bg="red", text=item_text) #updates label text - doesn't add multiple
        item1.grid()

addButton = Button(itemFrame, text="Add Button", padx=25, pady=25, command=AddButton)
addButton.grid()

f_blank = Frame(root, width=500, height=100)        ####added a blanc frame
f_blank.grid(row=0, column=1)



root.mainloop()
```